# what is difference between rtmp and rtsp protocol?

Tags: java, android, rtsp, rtmp

i just want to know what is the difference between rtsp and rtmp protocol and if  there are mp3s on my server and i am playing it in my android using http,how these differs in work.

In android if i want to implement rtmp or rtsp ,which is the best?
what are the limitation of rtmp & rtsp in android?

can anybody give me brief answer for above?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The Real Time Streaming Protocol (**RTSP**) is a network control protocol designed for use in entertainment and communications systems to control streaming media servers. The protocol is used for establishing and controlling media sessions between end points. Clients of media servers issue VCR-like commands, such as play and pause, to facilitate real-time control of playback of media files from the server.

Real Time Messaging Protocol (**RTMP**) was initially a proprietary protocol developed by Macromedia for streaming audio, video and data over the Internet, between a Flash player and a server.

I would use HTTP to stream MP3.

Comment: ¿Which one is best for transmiting data like a whiteboard?

Comment: "I would use HTTP to stream MP3."
more information on your opinion would help

Comment: If use RTMP, means we MUST have Flash player in client side?!

Comment: RTMP does not require Flash Player. Both VLC and ffmpeg supports RTMP. Librtmp can be used in an Android app. Probably many others as well. @Matthijs your comment is incorrect.

Comment: You did not answer the question at all

Answer (score 14):

They are both protocols for Streaming Media and on a high level achieve the same thing - Specify a standard to stream media.
Although  RTMP was developed and owned by Adobe before being made public , whereas RTSP was a public standard from the beginning. 
Since RTMP is mostly used by Flash player , i would assume that the android media player class  streams using RTSP.

Comment: The Android Media Player class can indeed be used for playing RTSP streams, but this does not mean that all Android devices can play the video since that depends on the capabilities of the device's chipset. The H.264 codec knows different [profiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Profiles) and [levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Levels) and not every Android device can decode the same profiles/levels. To make sure every device can decode the video, a framework could be used.

Comment: The question is about MP3-streaming.