# Live Streaming from Flash Media Server To Android devices

Tags: android, rtsp, rtmp

I'm developing an android application to stream a live TV  in Tunisia.
They have their server for streaming on the Web. they use Flash Media Server and rtmp protocol for streaming.
So, I have a problem with some devices that don't support flash media player.
Can you please help me to find a solution  like convert rtmp to rtsp or any other solution 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

your question is very vague. If you need to install flash on some devices on which it isn't installed, then you have to do it manually via the

> adb install your_path/flash.apk

As you know that flash isn't on the app store any more. The link to download the apk is [this](http://d-h.st/x4v). Go to that page and download the apk.

Secondly if you want to know about RTMP(Real Time Messaging Protocol) and RTSP(Real Time Streaming Protocol) then [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023335/what-is-difference-between-rtmp-and-rtsp-protocol) will help you.

Comment: thank you for you, and sorry for my bad English. What would I know if that is solution to convert rtmp from FMS to rtsp

Comment: Am sorry. I cant help you there. I haven't worked on rtmp nor rtsp.